# expression type add not support in C# windows application

Tags: cypher

I need to use C# for data from neo4j DB, By condition from textbox but it doesn't work

```
      var apps = client.Cypher
      .Match("(a:App)")
      .Where((APP a) => a.Name == "" + textBox1.Text + "")
      .Return(a => a.As<APP>())
      .Results;
```

Error message :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred
>   in Neo4jClient.dll

Comment: Please add the errors or exceptions observed while executing this code.

Comment: @Daenarys it show like this "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in Neo4jClient.dll"